# How to redirect the following using Jetty web server?

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, jetty

How would I redirect the follow using Jetty?:

```
domain.com/area1  --> area1.domain.com
www.domain.com  --> area1.domain.com
domain.com  --> area1.domain.com
```

Is it rewrite rules? If so what file do I edit and what rules would I add?

Thanks for your help.